# Can't find mysql.sock after power failure

Tags: mysql

I have a web server which was running fine until we had a power failure today. After bringing the server back online, the website hosted on it is failing because it can't connect to MySQL.

When I try to login to mysql via mysql -u root -p, I get the following:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)

So I searched the server for mysql.sock and can't find it at all. It's like it was deleted during the power failure.

How can I get mysql back up and running, and where should I point my.cnf to since I can't find the sock file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql.sock file is created when mysql starts and is removed upon mysql shutdown.  You should not, as suggested create a mysql.sock file yourself. Actually, creating one in the data directory yourself can interfere with the creation of one upon starting mysql.

The mysql.sock file is a unix socket that is used to facilitate the transport of data from client to server. The default location for the Unix socket file that the server uses for communication with local clients, in a vanilla mysql install, is `/tmp/mysql.sock`. The location can also be set in your `my.cnf` and may look like:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

> If, when you attempt to log in, you get an error message such as ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2), it means that the MySQL server daemon (Unix) or service (Windows) is not running.

You can read more at these links: [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting-disconnecting.html) or [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

This post may also help you from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/279366/what-should-mysqld-sock-contain-why-dont-i-have-it)